# Ternary Javascript for HTML (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

how can I change the following to ternary so I can use it in .HTML file

```
if (statusChange && statusChange === 'Employed') {
  return true;
} else {
  return employmentStatus === 'Employed'
}
```

i.e. assign the result of the second comparison only if the first `if` statement results to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```js
return statusChange && statusChange === 'Employed' ? true : employmentStatus === 'Employed'
```

Comment: Note that this expression has the same result as `statusChange === 'Employed' || employmentStatus === 'Employed'`

Answer (score 2):

No need for ternary operation here, just use the or operation:

```
statusChange === 'Employed' || employmentStatus === 'Employed'
```

If the first part is true, the whole expression will return true. If it's false, it will check it the second part is true or false

Much cleaner

Comment: much cleaner indeed. thanks for answering